# imeOption="actionNext" not working in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I am using floating hint from material design. I want to shift focus from one `EditText` to the next, So  I have put `imeOptions="actionNext"` in all editTexts and `imeOptions="actionDone` in the last `EditText`. But focus is not shifting to next `EditText`.

**Below is the snippet of my xml.**

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/streetWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputStyle">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Street/Locality *"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/flatWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputStyle">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Building Name / Flat Number*"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: try putting android:imeOptions="actionNext" to TextInputLayout

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should add **`android:imeOptions="actionNext"`** in **`EditText`** section.

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/streetWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputStyle">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: there is no attribute as ` android:imeOptions=""` in TextnputLayout.

Comment: yeah same thing . basically `imeOptions` is not an attribute .

Comment: sorry sorry , add `android:inputType="text"`  and `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`in your EditText section

Comment: ohh it's working fine now. 
`android:inputType` did the work. So what I get is all the EditTexts should have `inputType` as their attribute.
Thanks

Comment: If you want more than one line, it is not necessary to add                          android:maxLines="1"
 , for example if it is a TextInputLayoutBox: With                 android:inputType="text"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
 It's enough

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya How to hide soft keyboard after hit ```actionDone```?

Answer (score 7):

Add attribute `android:inputType="text"` to your `EditText`.

**Try this:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/streetWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Street/Locality *"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/flatWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Building Name / Flat Number*"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add **android:inputType="text"** on section Tag

If you not adding inputType imeOption is not work

Try this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimens_16dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_impian"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/text_fill_your_dream_here"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/color_green_manulife"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to also add `android:nextFocusForward="@id/secondInput"`. Make sure you are adding id's on `TextInputEditText` and not on `TextInputLayout`.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="First input">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/firstInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:nextFocusForward="@id/secondInput">

        <requestFocus />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Second input">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/secondInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```